# select-string use in a for-each loop

Tags: powershell, loops, select-string

I am working on building a script that will access a large amount of files and pull a specific string out in order to assign as a variable.

The string is similar across all files which is not the issue. I am able to make this process function as an individual event (define a single source file)

```
$hostname_import = select-string .\test.txt -Pattern 'hostname ABC-.+'
$hostname = $hostname_import -replace '.+ ',''
```

The above would output the specific hostname identified in the target file (the second function is to trim the word hostname and the space) I can then use this to proceed with using the variable as needed to perform various actions.

The issue I am having is executing this function in a foreach loop so that I can grab the initial file- execute the select-string function (or similar) and then perform the data modification within the loop as expected.

For context- I am going through configuration files- and building a separate file based on those configurations to report on findings- part of the report building requires the hostname of the device.

--**EDIT 1:**
After consulting with my rubber duck I will be attempting to import these files as CSVs in order to potentially reach a solution.

- Thanks @Otter for getting me through that. I had a previous script that used this function but for whatever reason I couldn't execute the function as anticipated. The difference between my previous script and this one was the $_.Fullname

Huge help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) can directly process *multiple* files via its `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` parameter, as an *array* of paths and/or as wildcard expressions.

What it doesn't support is passing a *directory* path in order to process the files in it (let alone *recursively*), so for that you'll have pipe the results of a [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) (possibly with `-Recurse`) to the `Select-String` call.

The following example uses the latter technique, looping over all `*.config` files in the current directory's subtree:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.config |
  Select-String -Pattern 'hostname ABC-(.+)' |
   ForEach-Object {
     $sourceFilePath = $_.Path
     $hostName = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
   }
```

Note the use of a capture group (`(...)`) inside the regex pattern, which allows extracting only the substring of interest from the overall match, via the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that `Select-String` outputs. This obviates the need for the `-replace` operation; see the bottom section for details.

Note that *multiple* matches may be reported per file; if you know that there's only *one* (or are only interested in the *first*), add `-List` to the `Select-String` call to speed up the operation.

---

**How to extract only the *text* (string) of a matching line / line part:**

When you use `Select-String` output objects (which are of type `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`) *directly* in *string* contexts such as `-replace`, the resulting string representation contains  *more* than just the *line text* if a file argument was given, because the input file path is prepended to the line text, followed by `:`; e.g.:
`C:\path\to\file.config:hostname ABC-foo`

To **extract the *line text only***, directly as a string, **use the `.Line` property**.

- Note: In PowerShell (Core) 7+ you can now ask `Select-String` to output strings (matching lines) *directly*, by passing the `-Raw` switch.

To **extract only the *part* of the line *that the regex matched*, use the `.Matches` property** (n/a if the `-SimpleMatch` switch for literal substring matching was also passed), as shown above.

- `.Matches` is a collection of [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instances (there can only be *multiple* elements if the `-AllMatches` switch was passed), the `.Value` property of each contains the *text* that matched the pattern overall.
- If the `-Pattern` regex contains *capture groups* (`(...)`), each `Match` instance's `.Groups` collection - itself composed of `Match` instances - contains what these groups captured, starting with index `1`; again the `.Value` property contains the captured *text*.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a `Get-ChildItem` which will fetch all files in a folder then pipe the output to a `Foreach-Object` loop which will reference the each file.

Note that I have added the `-recurse` switch in case you need to fetch subfolders files too.

Try the below:

```
Get-Childitem -path "C:\PathToFolder" -recurse | Foreach-Object {
    $hostname_import = select-string $_.Fullname -Pattern 'hostname ABC-.+'
    $hostname = $hostname_import -replace '.+ ',''
    
    # The rest of your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: This works, but it is inefficient to call `Select-String` once per input file; it's better to pipe the `Get-ChildItem` output directly to `Select-String`. Also, to only operate on the _text_ of the matching line, use `$hostname_import.Line`.